# Failed to query/invoke Hyperledger Fabric Peers(in a docker swarm network) via NodeJS - GRPC/S deadline Error

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc

**Process**
I've installed, queried, invoked fabcar chaincode via CLI. Everything was successful.

enrolAdmin.js and registerUser.js successfully worked.

**BUT** when I ran **query.js** I've got the following error

**Error**

```
error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://192.168.56.171:7051
error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://192.168.56.171:8051
error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://192.168.56.171:8051
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://192.168.56.171:8051
```

FYI - I've tested the same with both TLS disabled and enabled. Still fails

**Environment**
I've extended Hyperledger Fabric first-network e2e to work in multiple hosts with the help of docker swarm.

Connection profile (**without** TLS) as follows

```
{
    "name": "first-network",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.example.com",
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {},
                "peer1.org1.example.com": {},
                "peer0.org2.example.com": {},
                "peer1.org2.example.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        },
        "Org2": {
            "mspid": "Org2MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org2.example.com",
                "peer1.org2.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org2.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://192.168.56.170:7050"
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://192.168.56.171:7051"
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://192.168.56.171:8051"
        },
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://192.168.56.172:7051"
        },
        "peer1.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://192.168.56.172:8051"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "http://192.168.56.171:7054",
            "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
        },
        "ca.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "http://192.168.56.172:7054",
            "caName": "ca.org2.example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet of docker-compose file structure as follows,

```
networks:
  hyperledger:
        external: 
            name: hyperledger
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    -----------------------
    -----------------------
    -----------------------
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
    networks:
      hyperledger:
        aliases:
         - peer0.org1.example.com
```

**Expected Result** - Connect to Hyperledger docker swarm containers via NodeJS

Comment: Do you tried to increase the connection timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for the issue.
Make sure telnet works to the desired container from outside the network. By running

```
telnet 192.168.128.171 7051
```

**If Telnet doesn't work** --> The issue must because that ports are not published/exposed properly.
1st check the following,

Make sure CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS is set to listen to desired port in docker-compose files. As follows,
For peer0.org1.eaxmple.com --> 7051,

```
CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
```

**If Telnet works** -->  Check the connection profile. 
If TLS is enabled, make sure the tls certificates/PEM files are passed properly and connection is set to **GRPCS** (not GRPC)

**Connection Profile**

```
            "certificateAuthorities": [

                "ca.org1.example.com"

            ],

            "adminPrivateKey": {

                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_sk"

            },

            "signedCert": {

                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"

            }
```

```
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {

            "url": "grpcs://192.168.128.171:7051",

            "grpcOptions": {

                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com",

                "request-timeout": 120001

            },

            "tlsCACerts": {

                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"

            }

        },
```

Have a look at the following link for further reference
https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-network-config.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use domain.
modify /etc/hosts

```
192.168.100.100 peer0.org1.example.com
192.168.100.100 peer1.org1.example.com
192.168.100.100 orderer.example.com
192.168.100.100 orderer.example.com
192.168.100.100 orderer3.example.com
192.168.100.100 orderer4.example.com
192.168.100.100 orderer5.example.com
```

modify connection-org1.json

```
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051",


"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051",
```

modify code

```
await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false } });
```